# POST API request pass complex object

Tags: ios, swift

My code base is very lecacy.
the requirement is to pass the dictionary to the API request

API request partial format - (JSON)

```
{ .......
"notes": {
    "notesPreference": {
      "isCommonNotes": false,
      "isStudyNotes": false
    },
    "instruction": "No Instruction"
  }}
```

Since the code base is big, so sharing a piece of code
In the API parameter setting...

```
var payload = [String: Any]()
...... other existing params
payload["myNotes"] = ["instruction" : "No Instruction", "notesPreference" : [["isCommonNotes" : false , "isStudyNotes" : true ]] ]
```

when I print or API call request, Unfortunately, `payload["myNotes"]` is not passed.
any idea?

Existing code was not done using codable.

I am new to Swift and IT. Please correct me if anything is wrong here

I tried above code base, but not working

Comment: Have a look at `Codable` structs. Please try to create a [mre].

Comment: Show how you make your request. It's currently unclear what you send. But currently, `notesPreference` is an array in your Swift code, but a Dictionary on the JSON code.

Comment: You must post code that how you're encoding and setting http `body` is the only way to find out the issue.